# Clean way of using a python dictionary to hold program statistics

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I often write short programs when collect statistics when they run and report at the end. I normally gather these stats in a dictionary to display at the end.

I end up writing these like the simple example below, but I expect there is a cleaner more pythonic way to do this. This way can grow quite large (or nested) when there are several metrics.

```
stats = {} 

def add_result_to_stats(result,func_name):
    if not func_name in stats.keys():
        stats[func_name] = {}
    if not result in stats[func_name].keys():
        stats[func_name][result] = 1
    else:
        stats[func_name][result] += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which would reduce `add_result_to_stats` to one line:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
stats = defaultdict(Counter)

def add_result_to_stats(result, func_name):
    stats[func_name][result] += 1

add_result_to_stats('foo', 'bar')
print stats # defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, {'bar': Counter({'foo': 1})})
```

Comment: I prefer this answer for its print-ability

Answer (score 1):

If you just have to count `func_names` and `results` go with a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
import collections
stats = collections.Counter()

def add_result_to_stats(result,func_name):
    stats.update({(func_name, result):1})
```